# Hide and display images for a time in a special time period

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I want to display two images which should change every 50 seconds. Each image should be displayed for 120 seconds.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var dir = "0";
    setInterval(function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("maincontainer");           
        if(element.style.display == "none") {
            if(dir == "1") {
                dir = "0";  
            } else {
                dir = "1";  
            }               
            loadNewImages(dir); 
            element.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    }, 50000);
```

Some simple HTML code with a div container:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
 <img src="myimage.png" />
</div>
```

I try to play around with:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   element.style.display = "none"; 
}
), 
120000)
```

But this did not work.

I need a solution in plain JavaScript. With jQuery I can simply use `delay` or other magic.

Can someone give me a hint how to achieve my requirement?

Comment: why do you want to do this in plain javascript, when you know the solution with jQuery?

Comment: @BrechtSchepens because I simply cannot use it. I only want to be sure that no one give me a solution how to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a cycle pattern.  Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UmVGm/) (using 1.2 seconds to save you 1.98 minutes).

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

We wrap this in a closure so we can control our `i` variable.

```
(function(){
    var i = 0;
```

The first thing we do in our interval is to hide the current image, which is images[i].

```
    setInterval(function(){
        images[i].style.display = "none";
```

The we check and see if i+1 would be a valid image.  You could also write this as `images[i+1] != null`.  If we can increment it, we do.  Otherwise we start back at 0.  With two images this toggles between 0 and 1.  With 5 images it cycles 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, ...

```
        if (i+1 < images.length) {
            i++;
        }
        else {
            i = 0;
        }
```

Our new image is displayed.  This will be image[i] when the timer runs again, so it will be hidden.

```
        images[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    }, 120000);
})();
```

Comment: Okay...this changes the pictures immediately every 120000 ms. But how to say for "50 seconds display no picture"?

Comment: Wrap all of this in a setTimeout with a 50*1000 delay.